# variable assigned at the end of a module

Tags: python, class, variables

I have a quick question about how variables are passed from 1 module to another.

Scenarios:

I have 2 scripts, 1 name a.py and b.py.

```
## a.py
import datetime
import numpy as np
import os

class LOG:
    testid = ""
    log_f = None
    perf_log_f = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.testid = ""

def setTestId (testid, log_f , perf_log_f):
    log_v.testid = comp
    log_v.log_f = open(log_f , 'w')
    log_v.perf_log_f = open(perf_log_f, 'w')

log_v = LOG()
```

l is initiated

```
## b.py
from a import *

testid = 999
log_f = "kk.log"
perf_log_f = "kk_perf.log"
setTestId (testid, log_f , perf_log_f)

#### Does this setTestId do this step?  
"log_v.log_f = open("kk.log", 'w')
"log_v.perf_log_f = open("kk_perf.log", 'w')
```

Make the amendment. So when I call `setTestId` (imported from `a`) into `b.py`, `log_v = LOG()` is only contained within `a.py`, right?

I would like to check if the the variable `log_v` in `a.py` will be overwritten if we assign `log_v` to another variable in `b.py`

Comment: assuming your indentation is correct the answer is no.

Comment: you are calling `l.selfTestId` on `l` but your method is not part of the class `LOG`. Check your indentation or refresh OOP concepts

Comment: Naming a variable "l" is too ambiguous, try to name it properly and for your answer it is no.

Comment: Let's put it this way: `l` in `b.py` will be exactly what `l` is in `a.py`.

Comment: so the c = Clog() is contain within scripts a.py? and if I have a variable c in b.py, this is not related to the c in a.py>? I apologise for my bad OOP concepts. Also, the indentation is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

`LOG()` class is initiated at importing of `a.py`. It is assigned to the instance `log_v`

In `b.py`, when I call the functions `setTestId (testid, log_f , perf_log_f)`, it passes the arguments,  `testid, log_f , perf_log_f` to `log_v` to `a.py` and allow the initialization of the class with these variables.

Hence suppose I have a new functions `logging()` in `a.py` that uses `log_v`, by simply importing `a.py` and call the function `logging()`, I am able to access the class `LOG()` using the instance `log_v` that is contained within `a.py` and make any modification or updates to the class. This `log_v` is also protected from the scripts in `b.py` so it does not get overwritten if we also have another instance or variable name `log_v` in `b.py`